# Is there a better way to write this switch in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have a `switch` with the following conditions:

- The first `case` is `or` between three names (ROKA, MOKA and TOKA).
- The second `case` is another name (KOKA) but with two additional conditions to display an `alert`.
- Lastly, I have some other conditions to check inside the `default` block, as I'm unable to use a `case` for them.

This is my code:

```
var myname= 'JOKA';
var dhaba = false;

switch (myname) {
  case ('ROKA'):
  case ('MOKA'):
  case ('TOKA'):
    alert('EEE');
    break;

  case ('KOKA'):
    // This will work as Goto to final default:

    if (condition1 && condition2) {
      alert('FEEE');
      break;
    }

  default:
    if (dhaba && myname != 'ROKA' && myname != 'TOKA') {
      alert('TEEEE');
    } else {
      alert('CHEEE');
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: You may use strategy pattern

Comment: @Obrit: I don't understand how it fits in above scenario. Actually in those alerts there are confirm boxes only.

http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/strategy-design-pattern

Comment: @fatherazrael I guess you mean just JavaScript and not jQuery as switch is a JavaScript construction, completely independent from jQuery.

Comment: I don't see any jQuery in your code.

Comment: @fatherazrael Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 1):

When you reach `default`, then `myname` is always unequal to the previously checked values. It is sufficient to use

```
default:
    if (dhaba) {
        alert('TEEEE');
    } else {
        alert('CHEEE');
    }
```

Comment: Nice Catch. :) Any more suggestions?

Comment: @fatherazrael, actually not, because it's not clear, what you like to do more.

Answer (score 1):

I think `switch` is not the best option for your use case.

Also, as @NinaScholz has pointed out, the `myname != 'ROKA' && myname != 'TOKA'` will always be true, as otherwise you will fall in the first `case`.

Let's go step by step and see different ways to refactor your code:

#### Simplified (Non-Switch) Code

The easies and most straightforward way to write your code is like this:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';
const dhaba = false;

if ('ROKA' === myname || 'MOKA' === myname || 'TOKA' === myname) {
    alert('EEE');
} else if (myname === 'KOKA' && true && true) {
    alert('FEEE');
} else {
    alert(dhaba ? 'TEEEE' : 'CHEEE');
}
```

Note how the redundant checks have been removed and the last `if - else` block have been replaced with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

---

It is possible that your code is not exactly like the example you provided or that it changes overtime. In that case, you may consider other options other than the above simplified code.

#### Checking multiple matches from a single variable using Array.prototype.indexOf()

However, you may have a lot more elements to check in the first `if`. In that case you could use an `Array` and [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control) to check if there's any match inside it (it will return `-1` if there isn't any):

```
const myname = 'JOKA';
const dhaba = false;

if (['ROKA', 'MOKA', 'TOKA'].indexOf(myname) !== -1) {
    alert('EEE');
} else if (myname === 'KOKA' && true && true) {
    alert('FEEE');
} else {
    alert(dhaba ? 'TEEEE' : 'CHEEE');
}
```

#### N Input - Output (String) Pairs + Complex Default with Switch

It is also possible that you have multiple `myname` values that map to multiple `alert()` params, so you may feel tempted to write something like this:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';
const dhaba = false;

switch(myname) {
    case 'XXX-1': alert('YYY-1'); break;
    case 'XXX-2': alert('YYY-2'); break;

    ...

    case 'XXX-N': alert('YYY-N'); break;

    default:
        if (myname === 'KOKA' && true && true) {
            alert('FEEE');
        } else {
            alert(dhaba ? 'TEEEE' : 'CHEEE');
        }
}
```

While this is fine and, actually, I think it is cleaner and less error-prone than checking an additional condition inside a `case` block, as you did in your example, and based on that do something and `break` or let the next block execute, I would advise you to consider using object literal lookups instead.

#### N Input - Output (String) Pairs + Complex Default with Object Literals Lookups

There are multiple advantages to use them: better readability, easier debugging, maintainability, concision (no need to add `break`, for example)... I think the most important one for you, as you added the tag `performance` in your question, is that it is more performant.

This is because while the `switch` has to evaluate each `case` condition until it fins a `break`, so their order matters, the object lookup is just a hash table lookup, that is, `O(1)`.

With this in mind, we could refactor the last example like this:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';
const dhaba = false;

const output = {
    'XXX-1': 'YYY-1',
    'XXX-2': 'YYY-2',

    ...

    'XXX-N': 'YYY-N',
}[myname];

// Note output will be undefined if there isn't a match, so the first if
// will be evaluated to false in that scenario:

if (output) {
    alert(output);
} else if (myname === 'KOKA' && true && true) {
    alert('FEEE');
} else {
    alert(dhaba ? 'TEEEE' : 'CHEEE');
}
```

#### N Input - Output (String) Pairs + Single-Value Default with Object Literals Lookups  and || (or) Operator

Also, note that if your *default* were just using another value inside the `if`, you could do that with a simple `||` operator:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';

const output = {
    'XXX-1': 'YYY-1',
    'XXX-2': 'YYY-2',

    ...

    'XXX-N': 'YYY-N',
}[myname] || 'DEFAULT OUTPUT';

alert(output);
```

#### N Input - Output (Arbitrary Code) Pairs with Object Literals Lookups

Note you could also execute arbitrary code for each *case* in your objects using `functions` or `arrow functions`:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';

const output = {
    'XXX-1': () => { /* Do something... */ },
    'XXX-2': () => { /* Do something... */ },

    ...

    'XXX-N': () => { /* Do something... */ },
}[myname]();

...
```

Note that you could declare those `functions` above the object declaration and share them across multiple keys that should have the same behaviour:

```
const myname = 'JOKA';

const f1 = () => { /* Do something 1... */ };

const output = {
    'XXX-1': f1,
    'XXX-2': f1,

    ...

    'XXX-N': () => { /* Do something... */ },
}[myname]();

...
```

---

For more on replace `switchs` with object literal lookups, take a look at this post: https://toddmotto.com/deprecating-the-switch-statement-for-object-literals